# OpenGL GL_LINE_STRIP gives error 1281 (Invalid value) after glEnd

Tags: c++, python, opengl, ctypes

I have no idea what is wrong with the simple code. The function is for use with python and ctypes.

```
extern "C" void add_lines(bool antialias,GLdouble coordinates[][2],int array_size,GLdouble w,GLdouble r,GLdouble g, GLdouble b,GLdouble a){
    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    if (antialias){
        glEnable(GL_LINE_SMOOTH); //Enable line smoothing.
    }
    glColor4d(r,g,b,a);
    glLineWidth(w);
    glBegin(GL_LINE_STRIP);
    for (int x = 0; x < array_size; x++) {
        glVertex2d(coordinates[x][0],coordinates[x][1]);
    }
    glEnd();
    std::cout << glGetError();
    if (antialias){
        glDisable(GL_LINE_SMOOTH); //Disable line smoothing.
    }
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
}
```

std::cout << glGetError(); gives out 1281 each time.

Thankyou.

Comment: Add a similar cout at the beginning of the function to make sure the error happens inside it. It might have been the result of an earlier operation (glTexImage2d for example). In your code glLineWidth can generate that error if w is less than or equal to 0

Comment: Yes, you are right. The GLdouble is near zero for some reason. In the python script it is most often 1 but always goes to a very smaller number. I'll check the other double values.

Comment: Yes, all of them are very small. I'll see if I actually needed to convert them in ctypes beforehand. I thought ctypes converted numbers automatically though.

Comment: The error for the width is gone. The error for glEnd has not. :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`glGetError()`](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glGetError.xml) is sticky: once the error gets set by some function, it will stay at that error value until you call `glGetError()`.  So, the error is likely being caused elsewhere.  Check the value of `glGetError()` on function entry, and then after each function call to find out where it's being set.

Comment: Read what I put for the last answer. I will check it again though.

Comment: Whoops. I do get it after the glEnd but also after glLineWidth.

Comment: "width - 1.08222e-31"

There's my problem I guess. I'll see what I can do.

Comment: It works now that I've sorted the arguments out. Your answer pointed me to check glGetError properly again and then I spotted something I missed. Thank you and to everyone else.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the error is not triggered before glEnd? glGetError will report the last GL error, which might be caused earlier in program execution.

Comment: Thank you for your input. I used cout everywhere and then found out it originated after glEnd.